# Issue with adding a library: No such file or directory

Tags: library, ide, debugging

I downloaded a Library called "Morse" which I got from the Arduino website:

http://arduino.cc/en/Hacking/LibraryTutorial

(all the way at the bottom of the page there is a link called Morse.zip)
And basically added the library. Then when I import the library, it is included to the sketch. However when I try verifying it, the following error message appears:

[image]

*to see the image clearer you can right click it and click on "Open image in new tab"*

Basically it says:

In file included from sketch_nov28a.ino:1:
C:\Users\Marko\Documents\Arduino\libraries\Morse/Morse.h:10:22: error: WProgram.h: No such file or directory

Now I tried reinstalling the Arduino IDE, I tried adding the library again as well as using the manual method that was stated in that first link above, and the error persists.

What I did notice was that in that second line of the error message, something caught my eye: "...\Morse/Morse.h:10:22:..."
There is a forward slash!(/) Now it seems weird to me that with would happen, especially given that all the other examples I saw of this error online have a backslash (\). This could be the problem.... but even if it is, how do I fix it? I tried going to preferences... does anyone know?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That library is for the older version of the Arduino ide. To fix this you need to open `Morse.h` and change `WProgram.h` to `Arduino.h`.